# Documentation generation for BuckleScript project

Tags: ocaml, reason, bucklescript

Is there any way to generate code documentation for BuckleScript or Reason? I've tried using `ocamldoc`, but I don't know how to include node package dependencies automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an automatic resolution yet for node packages. You can manually specify each dependent package in the ocamldoc command, e.g.:

```
ocamldoc -html -d doc -I node_modules/bs-webapi/lib/ocaml -I node_modules/bs-fetch/lib/ocaml -I node_modules/bs-platform/lib/ocaml src/YourModule.re
```

The directory includes are fairly predictable, you just have to point at the `lib/ocaml` directories in each package, ocamldoc will find their compiled `.cmi` files and pull in the required type information from there.

This also means that you'll first need to have done `bsb -make-world`, to compile all those `.cmi`s.

Answer (score 0):

There’s a tool which, supposedly, automatically performs a lot of the orchestration of `ocamldoc` described by @Yawar, called [BsDoc](https://reuniverse.github.io/bsdoc/docs/bsdoc/).

Note that I have not used this myself; but it it supposed to be the go-to for a lot of BuckleScript-specific projects (i.e. using `bsb` with `npm`-installed dependencies, not `dune` with `opam`-installed dependencies.)